# What Azure RBAC API to use for getting roles for a specific user?

Tags: azure, rbac, azure-rbac, azure-video-indexer

1. Does the service offer a specific API for getting a role assignments for a user and not for a resources group/resource?
2. In a previous question that was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533897/how-to-get-list-of-all-roles-assignments-using-rbac-api),are there any plans to make the CLI response and the API similar regarding getting the 'roleDefinitionName' property?

Answer (score 0):

Found a partial answer.

1. For getting both role assigned for User and Group should use the following API:
   By adding the param `$filter` with the value of `assignedTo('{userObjectId}')`.
   Example:

   [https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?$filter=assignedTo('{userObjectId}')&api-version=2015-07-01](https://management.azure.com/%7Bscope%7D/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?$filter=assignedTo(%27%7BuserObjectId%7D%27)&api-version=2015-07-01)
2. Haven't find an answer yet.